# how to import text file into structs C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to import data from a text file into structs for use as i don't really want to import them into seperate arrays.
I keep getting "error: expected primary-expression before '[' token" on each getline, i'm terrible at C++ and basically using what C skills i have to try and make sense of this. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
#include "Ladybird.h"
using namespace std;



typedef struct managerImport{
    int gridSizeA;
    int gridSizeB;
    int aphidCount;
    int aphidPos;
    int ladyCount;
    int ladyPos;
    struct managerImport *next;
};

void importData(managerImport[]){

ifstream manager;
    manager.open("Manager.txt");
     if (!manager.fail()){

         //loops the 2d array
       for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
       { 
          getline(manager, managerImport[i].gridSizeA, managerImport[i].gridSizeB);
       }

       //loop the lady bird count
       for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
       { 
          getline(manager, managerImport[i].ladyCount);
       }

       //loops the lady bird coordinates
       for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
       { 
          getline(manager, managerImport[i].ladyPos);
       }

       for (int i = 10; i < 11; i++)
       { 
          getline(manager, managerImport[i].aphidCount);
       }

       //loops the lady bird coordinates
       for (int i = 11; i < 19; i++)
       { 
          getline(manager, managerImport[i].aphidPos);
       }
     }


   manager.close();

}


int main() {

  //importing the manager text file

importData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you name the argument in the function?

void importData(managerImport[]) just says you have a function importData that takes an array of type managerImport (your struct).

Edited for clarification:
Imagine I write this code:
int increment(int) { return int+1; }

What I've done is hand the compiler a function that takes an argument "int". Is "int" a type or the name of my argument? This obviously won't compile since the argument has to have both a type and a name (so even if I want want to name my argument "int" (not advised), I still need to supply a type which says what "int" actually is (type-wise). Is it a long, a string, an unsigned char? Assuming I meant to actually accept an int, add 1, and return the incremented value (an int), this is what I should have written:
int increment(int i) { return i+1; }

So, in your case, you have:
void importData(managerImport[]) { ... }

Obviously, you're meaning to accept an array of managerImport, but you haven't given that array a name. Try this:
void importData(managerImport foo[]) { .. }

Also, unless you really need a c-array, you might try using a vector or an C++ array (std::array).

Comment: I know theres something extreamly necessary missing i just can't work it out, I don't understand the question, what argument?

Comment: @AlexBoollayBull:  Did you use the debugger?  When you used the debugger, where is it presenting the issue?

Comment: I have changed the struct into an object and then an array
struct managerImport imp;
struct managerImport mi[20];

so the get line looks like this,
 getline(manager, mi[i].gridSizeA, mi[i].gridSizeB);

Comment: I didn't use a debugger. I just noticed the issue reading your code. Also, in your main method, you're not actually calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

**The function `getline` does not translate text into integers.  It simply copies text without translations.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{ 
  getline(manager, managerImport[i].gridSizeA, managerImport[i].gridSizeB);
}
```

Your `getline` function call translates to `getline(stream, int, int);`.

You will need to either use:

```
  manager >> managerImport[i].gridSizeA >> managerImport[i].gridSizeB;
```

or read in as string and parse out of the string.

Comment: So i just tried changng the call to more of a c++ request using 

      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
           { 
              getline(manager >> mi[i].gridSizeA >> mi[i].gridSizeB);
           }
and have named the array globally,
but it error returns 
 error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&)'

 note: candidates are:

 note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided

 note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: Reread my answer.  The best way is to use the stream extraction operator, `>>`.

Comment: It's working with the line you gave,  manager >> managerImport[i].gridSizeA >> managerImport[i].gridSizeB;. Thank you very much!!